# How can I use C++11/14 and target RHEL 5.5?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, redhat

I'm having difficulty finding any docs that list the valid versions of linux supported by Clang and GCC.  Can I use either of them to build C++11/14 source for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5?

EDIT:  The specific problem that I have been having is that recent versions of the libraries don't work, at least not the binary releases.  I was hoping to scope the needed work by finding something like a list of incompatible libraries, so that I didn't have to discover them one by one.

Comment: What do you mean with a compiler supporting an OS?

Comment: You can probably build the newest version of clang and gcc from source on your machine if that's what you are talking about.

Comment: @BaummitAugen and add a recent version of all the libraries you want to use. including the C/C++ runtime.